# Why are my storyboard views not iPhone-shaped?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am building an iPhone app, and the storyboard looks like this:

[image: my storyboard]

Notice that the views within the storyboard are awkwardly square. I wasn't sure what caused this so I just went with it.

I set my app as iPhone-only and portrait-only.

When I build the app on my phone though, parts of the view are off the screen, because my phone isn't shaped like the interfaces that I am building.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 6 Viewcontroller sized to 600*600 size, its for Auto layout and size classes. You can disable this feature by unchecking autolayout and size classes in the File inspector of storyboard (refer image). If you disable autolayout you can see your storyboard viewcontrollers sized to iphone.

[image: Disable autolayout and size class]

Answer (score 2):

It is **`Universal Storyboard`**.

Apple wants developer to create apps with **`Adaptive Layout`**

The introduction of Adaptive Layout in iOS 8 is a huge paradigm shift for iOS app designers. When designing your app, you can now create a single layout, which works on all current iOS 8 devices – without crufty platform-specific code.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) tutorial serves as your introduction to Adaptive Layout. You’ll learn about universal storyboards, size classes, layout and font customizations and the ultra-useful Preview Assistant Editor.

--Edit--

If you want to fix the size of storyboard you can adjust width and height.

[image: Resizing storyboard]